# How to make an voice command program to android using python?

Tags: android, python, voice-recognition

I have a school project and I have this idea for my android phone.

But I don't really know if it can be done and I don't know how I could do it.

Does someone know if it can be done? If not can you write a programme for android using python? What is the easiest way?

Comment: Please explain more about your idea for your school project.

Comment: It is possible to program an android app using python, but I refrained from answering because your question is vague. Does someone know if what can be done?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is using [AppInventor](http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/about/) from Google. It makes the programing of apps for Android a kids game.